# import react-native-esc-pos-printer shows error react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, thermal-printer, escpos

I am trying to print using bluetooth thermal esc pos printer from android but it shows the following errors

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'getConstants' of null, js engine: hermes`

code :

```
import EscPosPrinter, {
  getPrinterSeriesByName,
  IPrinter,
} from "react-native-esc-pos-printer";

return (
<View><Text>text<Text/><View/>
)
```

I have just imported this lib. and shows an error.
but run `npx expo run:android`

Env: react-native expo
Edit: or at least provide what package to use and give example if possible

Comment: Now I am using "react-native-thermal-printer"